# Parent not listening to child $emit - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Here is the child component:

```
Vue.component("training-edit", {
    template: "#training-edit-template",
    props: ["show"],
    data: function () {
        return {
            form: new Form(),
            isWorking: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        show: function (val) {
            if (val) {
                $("#editTrainingModal").modal("show");
            } else {
                $("#editTrainingModal").modal("hide");
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onCancel: function () {
            this.$emit("doneEditing");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the parent:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#trainingEditContainer",
    data: {
        isWorking: false,
        showEditTraining: false
    },
    methods: {
        onEdit: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.showEditTraining = true;
        },
        doneEditing: function () {
            this.showEditTraining = false; 
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="trainingEditContainer" class="row">
    // unrelated stuff here

    <training-edit v-bind:show="showEditTraining"></training-edit>
</div>
<script id="training-edit-template" type="x-template">
    <modal-right modalId="editTrainingModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" v-on:click="onCancel" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Training</h4>
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("Partial/_EditPartial")
    </modal-right>
</script>
```

I can see in the Vue Developer Tools in Chrome that the event is being emitted but for some reason, the parent is not hearing it and the `doneEditing` function is never called. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Bert The parent doesn't have a template but the child does, so I added that to the OP. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: It does. What are you attempting to `watch`? Watch should be an object. Beyond that, the main issue here appears to be that you never set up a listener for the `doneEditing` event.

Comment: @Bert Whoops, I've corrected the `watch` part, that was just a typo when posting here. How do I go about listening for the event? I thought the parent was always listening but I am still relatively new to `Vue` so I could be easily wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I recommend you change the name of the event to `done-editing`.

```
this.$emit("done-editing")
```

This is because attributes in HTML are case insensitive and if you are rendering some of your template to the DOM, it's just better all around to [avoid camelCased names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case). Note that this doesn't apply if you define the templates in strings or if you are using single file components.

Then you need to listen for it on the component.

```
<training-edit @done-editing="doneEditing" v-bind:show="showEditTraining">
```

When you emit an event from a component, the parent has to explicitly listen for the event.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thanks a bunch for your help and for the tip about HTML and camelCasing!

Comment: @Quiver No problem :)